# ThreeJS - How to convert 3d object to 2d representation

Tags: 3d, three.js, projection

I have a 3d model in ThreeJS. What are the techniques called to project 3d object to 2d ? For example, I would like to project 3d model to the ground. Here is the image of what I am looking for:
[image]

Is this even called a projection? How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is a projection onto a plane, the simple way to do it in three js is to take the geometry points and project them onto a plane

an example with bufferGeometry (normal geometry might iterate points other way or something..)

```
//create someplane to project to
var plane = new THREE.Plane().setFromCoplanarPoints(pointA,pointB,pointC)
//create some geometry to flatten..
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
fillGeometry(geometry);

var positionAttr = geometry.getAttribute("position");
for(var i = 0; i < positionAttr.array.length; i+=3)
{
    var point = new THREE.Vector3(positionAttr.array[i],positionAttr.array[i+1],positionAttr.array[i+2]);
    var projectedPoint = plane.projectPoint();
    positionAttr.array[i] = projectedPoint.x;
    positionAttr.array[i+1] = projectedPoint.y;
    positionAttr.array[i+2] = projectedPoint.z;
}
positionAttr.needsUpdate = true;
```

code above will flatten the geometry onto the plane given by 3 points, you can either process the array for something or use the geometry in scene as a pancake..